# Transfer image as blob via AJAX FormData to C# File Uploader

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmlhttprequest, blob, multipartform-data

The title says most of it. I have an image that I'm performing some manipulation on before I send it to be saved to the server. I'm saving the images as blobs, then appending them to a `FormData` object, and sending the whole FormData object upstream. This is where I'm having issues. Here is my JS function that sends the data:

```
function sendSlide(slide) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("name", slide.name);
    data.append("img_regular", slide.blob.regular, slide.filename);
    data.append("img_blurred", slide.blob.blurred, slide.filename);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "FileUpload.aspx");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            debugger;
        }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

This works fine. On the C# end of things, I'm able to read the `name` from `Request.Form` so I would assume everything is working properly. However trying to read `img_regular` or `img_blurred` doesn't work!

I guess this means I have two main questions.

1. How do I ensure that the image data is being sent?
2. How do I read the image data on the C# side?
3. What's the best way to save this data?

Thanks for your assistance!